# Search in Dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a set of dictionaries in a list and i need to eliminate those which contains a specific word and return the other dictionaries to a list.

```
P = {u'data': 
[{u'data': [{u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'NorthBoundPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0C:9G:2F:FA', u'epg': u'dmzInternet', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb1b', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'RR-az1VPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0D:9F:1B:FB', u'epg': u'dmzTransit', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb15', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-127', u'endpoint': u'eth1/4', u'cep': u'00:09:6G:6C:6B:E2', u'epg': u'App', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a3b52af58fc536d710', u'tenant': u'CRL', u'extpaths': None}]}
```

i used FOR loop and IF inside it to match the character `RR` . Logic is if `RR` present in `endpoint` then ignore it. e.g. in 2nd dictionary its present.

```
hosts = []
for record in P:           
    if record["endpoint"] and  "RR" not in record["endpoint"]:
        hosts.append(record)
return hosts
```

its throwing below error :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: throwing error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Where is the `host_details` variable?

Comment: which line throws it?

Comment: What is `host_details`? The same as `P`? Your `P` is incorrect there is `]}` missing at the end! Just do a `print record`  or `print P[record]` inside your loop.

Comment: it throws error at the line with "if" condition

Comment: Probably because the input is not well formatted as @OcasoProtal said.

Comment: @dome No, not because of the input, but because of the data structure of the input... A dict of lists of a dict, there is more than one simple ´for` needed.

Comment: That's true, I didn't see that the data structure was nested.

Comment: there is ]} at the end

Comment: Yes, but there is additional `]}` missing. Did you tried the code you are posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `P` is invalid, you need an additional `]}` at the end:

```
P = {u'data': 
[{u'data': [{u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'NorthBoundPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0C:9G:2F:FA', u'epg': u'dmzInternet', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb1b', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'RR-az1VPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0D:9F:1B:FB', u'epg': u'dmzTransit', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb15', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-127', u'endpoint': u'eth1/4', u'cep': u'00:09:6G:6C:6B:E2', u'epg': u'App', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a3b52af58fc536d710', u'tenant': u'CRL', u'extpaths': None}]}]}
```

So, you have a dictionary with (one) string key (`data`) and a list of dictionaries as value. That list has exactly one element, again a dictionary with a list of dictionaries (what a weird data structure, you should try to simplify that structure):

```
[{u'data': [{u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'NorthBoundPC', u'cep': 
 u'00:00:0C:9G:2F:FA', u'epg': u'dmzInternet', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': 
 u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb1b', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, {u'paths': 
 u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'RR-az1VPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0D:9F:1B:FB', u'epg': 
 u'dmzTransit', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb15', u'tenant':    
 u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, {u'paths': u'paths-127', u'endpoint': u'eth1/4',     
 u'cep': u'00:09:6G:6C:6B:E2', u'epg': u'App', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': 
 u'5c7616a3b52af58fc536d710', u'tenant': u'CRL', u'extpaths': None}]}]
```

There are three dictionaries in that list. That is the list you want to filter!
So looking at your code we see a `for record in P:` which is short for `for record in P.keys():`. With the examination of your data structure it's very obvious that this is not enough looping.

We need to loop three time to get where we want:

```
hosts = []
for k in P:
 for outerlist in P[k]:
  for record in outerlist[kk]:
   if "RR" not in record.get("endpoint", ""):
    hosts.append(record)
```

I've also shortend the `if` to use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Answer (score 1):

I reformalised your example data as follows:

```
P=[{u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'NorthBoundPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0C:9G:2F:FA', u'epg': u'dmzInternet', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb1b', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'RR-az1VPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0D:9F:1B:FB', u'epg': u'dmzTransit', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb15', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, 
 {u'paths': u'paths-127', u'endpoint': u'eth1/4', u'cep': u'00:09:6G:6C:6B:E2', u'epg': u'App', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a3b52af58fc536d710', u'tenant': u'CRL', u'extpaths': None}]
```

The above is a list of dictionaries.

When I run your code on this list:

```
hosts = []
for record in P:           
    if record["endpoint"] and  "RR" not in record["endpoint"]:
        hosts.append(record) # no need for a 'return' line as this is not a function- just append the wanted data to 'hosts'
```

I get:

```
hosts
[{u'paths': u'paths-117', u'endpoint': u'NorthBoundPC', u'cep': u'00:00:0C:9G:2F:FA', u'epg': u'dmzInternet', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a4b52af58fc536eb1b', u'tenant': u'dmz', u'extpaths': None}, {u'paths': u'paths-127', u'endpoint': u'eth1/4', u'cep': u'00:09:6G:6C:6B:E2', u'epg': u'App', u'pod': u'pod-1', u'_id': u'5c7616a3b52af58fc536d710', u'tenant': u'CRL', u'extpaths': None}]
```

I hope this helps you- I think you were just structuring the 'set' of dictionaries incorrectly... You made a dictionary with a key- data and the value for that was a list of more dictionaries- I think it might be easier to have a list of dictionaries. I'm not sure though- it depends on what your trying to achieve...